# How to replace the character string after the third comma

Tags: awk, gsub

I want to replace / with "/" after the third comma.

[expedted]

```
AAA,BB/B,CCC,D/D,EEE
```

↓

```
AAA,BB/B,CCC,D”/”D,EEE
```

[what I tried]

```
cat sample.txt | awk '        
    {
        gsub( /, "/", $1 )
        print $1 , $2
    }
'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Simple explanation would be, setting `FS` and `OFS` as `,` and in main block substituting `/` with `"/"` in 4th field and mentioning `1` will print edited/non-edited line.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {sub("/","\"/\"",$4)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation using the hex character code for `"` (`\x22`) and the character list `[/]` for your regex, you could do:

```sh
awk -F, -v OFS="," '{sub(/[/]/,"\x22/\x22",$4)}1' file
```

**Example Use/Output**

In your case that would be:

```sh
$ echo "AAA,BB/B,CCC,D/D,EEE" | awk -F, -v OFS="," '{sub(/[/]/,"\x22/\x22",$4)}1'
AAA,BB/B,CCC,D"/"D,EEE
```

Answer (score 0):

not as elegant as i hoped :

```
AAA,BB/B,CCC,D/D,EEE
                     >>>
                         AAA,BB/B,CCC,D"/"D,EEE


# gawk profile, created Tue May 17 02:51:22 2022

BEGIN {
         _ = substr("\35\3\5",\
  (__ = (_ = (_="[^,]*[,]")(_)_)(\
  OFS = FS = "[/]") "*")^sub(FS,"^&",__)^gsub("[:-~]","\"",OFS))

} ($-_)~((__)FS) ? sub(__,"&"_)*sub((_)FS, OFS) : !-_'
```